# Maven systemPath - transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available

Tags: maven

In my Maven based project `A` I have added following artifact from system path:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.11</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/opencv-2411.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

and now have an error in a project `B` that depends on a previous one:

```
[WARNING] The POM for ...name:jar:0.9.4-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

Right now I can't launch my project `B` by a following Spring Boot Maven plugin command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

with a lot of ClassNotFoundExceptions

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Obviously - don't use system dependencies. The opencv is even available in public repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv/2.4.11-2

Comment: Never use system scoped dependencies. And yes system scoped dependencies are not transitive because from where should the picked up?